# How to get all users From Owners Group in SharePoint 2013 for a subsite

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, sharepoint-server, jquery-ui

I am trying to get all the Users from a SharePoint Owner's Group for a subsite. Below Script is Working fine . But it displays both Site and Subsite Users of Owner's Group.

For example If **SITE A** has **SITEOWNERS GROUP** and it has **SUBSITE A1** . Now when i use this Script in sub site, It should Display the users from **SUBSITEOWNERS GROUP**. Howeever it Displays users from  Both S**ITEOWNERS GROUP &  SUBSITEOWNERS GROUP**. Can any one Help me on this to correct my Code.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.com/Style%20Library/JAVASCRIPT/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>
<div id='tblMain' style="float:left">
 <table id="myUsersTable"  border="1" cellpadding="2" width="400px">
    <tr>
    <th>OwnerName</th>
    <th>OwnerEmail</th>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
var currentcontext = null; 
var currentweb = null; 
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', GetGroups);
});

function GetGroups() 
{ 
currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 

currentweb = currentcontext.get_web(); 

this.groupCollection = currentweb.get_siteGroups(); 

currentcontext.load(this.groupCollection); 

currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.ExecuteOnSuccess), 
Function.createDelegate(this, this.ExecuteOnFailure)); 
} 
function ExecuteOnSuccess(sender, args) 
{ 
var listEnumerator = this.groupCollection.getEnumerator(); 
while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) 
{ 
var item = listEnumerator.get_current(); 
groupName = item.get_title(); 
//alert(groupName); 
    if (groupName.toLowerCase().indexOf("owners") >= 0)
    {
        alert(groupName); 
    GetData(groupName);
    }
} 
} 

function ExecuteOnFailure(sender, args) 
{ 
alert("error"); 
} 

function GetData(groupName)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('" + groupName +"')/users",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose", 
        },
          success: getUsersFromGroupSuccessHandler,
          error: getUsersFromGroupErrorHandler
           });    
}
function getUsersFromGroupSuccessHandler(data) 
{
         checkUsers = data.d.results.length;
         var Owners = [];

        if (checkUsers == 0) 
        {

            alert ("There are no results for this");
        }
        else 
        {
            $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item)
            {
                var OwnerName = item.Title;
                var OwnerEmail= item.Email;

                AddRowToTable(OwnerName,OwnerEmail);

               });
            //console.log(Owners);


        }


}

function AddRowToTable(OwnerName,OwnerEmail)
{   
$("#myUsersTable").append( 

                           "<tr>"+
                            "<td >" + OwnerName + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + OwnerEmail + "</td>"+
                            "</tr>"); 


}
function getUsersFromGroupErrorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage)
{
alert("Could not get users from group: " + errorMessage);
}

</script>
```

Comment: You are doing a lazy match on the owner group, `if (groupName.toLowerCase().indexOf("owners") >= 0)`, the more subsite you have, the more will appear. You need to be more explicit in the group you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting site collection groups earlier you are retrieving groups from the site collection, but when you execute your GetData() function, you are passing in a group name, but executing it at the root level.

```
http://site/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('Owners')/users
```

instead of

```
http://site/subsite/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('Owners')/users
```