# Using Object Model to Find Groups' Members Produces Frankentable

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, csom, jsom, groups

I modified the code here:

[How to get all users From Owners Group in SharePoint 2013 for a subsite](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138554/how-to-get-all-users-from-owners-group-in-sharepoint-2013-for-a-subsite)

to search for groups named "xxx Members" and their members.

To the code, I added:

```
function AddGroupNameRowToTable(GroupName)
{   
     $("#myUsersTable").append("<tr>" +
                               "<td colspan=2>" + GroupName + "</td>" +
                               "</tr>"); 
}
```

and a call to it at the end of function ExecuteOnSuccess:

```
GroupName = item.get_title();
if (GroupName.indexOf(" Members") >= 0)
      {
          //alert(GroupName); 
          AddGroupNameRowToTable(GroupName);
          GetData(GroupName);
```

The problem is, I get:

```
Gardeners Members
Horticulturists Members
Fred     Fred@xxxcom
Jed      Jed@xxxcom
Lucy     Lucy@xxxcom
Ron      Ron@xxxcom
Tilly    Tilly@xxxcom
```

I want to see this (spacing and dash lines for clarity):

```
Gardeners Members
-----------------
Fred     Fred@xxxcom
Jed      Jed@xxxcom

Horticulturists Members
-----------------------
Lucy     Lucy@xxxcom
Ron      Ron@xxxcom
Tilly    Tilly@xxxcom
```

It looks like the functions are executing asynchronously, such that the groups get listed first.

I don't know how to get the results I want.  The SP object model and coding style are new to me.

Thanks

Comment: what if you add some "width" attribute to your td tags on the AddGroupNameRowToTable function?
And if you want the "-------" spacer add a second row, <tr><td> tags

This is html format problem not sharepoint problem.

Comment: Marco, thanks, but this question is not about the formatting.  What I want to solve is the ordering of the output, per groups and members.

Answer (score 0):

The `GetData` function in your code is async so you need to add the function `AddGroupNameRowToTable(GroupName)` in its success handler. The sample code snippet is below for reference.

```
function GetData(groupName){
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('" + groupName +"')/users",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose", 
        },
        success: function(data){ 
            AddGroupNameRowToTable(groupName); 
            getUsersFromGroupSuccessHandler(data) 
        },
        error: getUsersFromGroupErrorHandler
    });    
}
function getUsersFromGroupSuccessHandler(data) 
{
    checkUsers = data.d.results.length;
    var Owners = [];

    if (checkUsers == 0){
        alert ("There are no results for this");
    }
    else{
        $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){
            var OwnerName = item.Title;
            var OwnerEmail= item.Email;

            AddRowToTable(OwnerName,OwnerEmail);

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see!  Thanks very much for showing the fix in the context of my code!

Answer (score 0):

The following code for your reference:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {      
    getGroupsUsers();   
});
function getGroupsUsers(){
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/SiteGroups?$filter=substringof('Members',Title)&$expand=Users";

    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
         headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
        success: function (data) {
            var html="<table >";
            var groups=data.d.results;
            for(var i=0;i<groups.length;i++){
                if(i>0){
                    html+="<tr><td colspan=2 style='border-bottom: dotted 2px black;'></td></tr>";
                }
                html+="<tr><td colspan=2><b>"+groups[i].Title+ "</b></td></tr>";
                var users=groups[i].Users.results;
                for(var j=0;j<users.length;j++){
                    html+="<tr><td>"+users[j].Title+"</td><td>"+users[j].Email+"</td></tr>";
                }           
            }
            html+="</table>";
            $("#groupUsers").html(html);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            //alert("Failed to get details");                
        }
    });
}
</script>
<div id="groupUsers"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: This is excellent!  Compact and understandable!  Thank you so much for adding this.  I learned a lot from it.

Currently, all of my users are in SharePoint Groups, and the code enumerates those users perfectly.  Once I am given permission by the higher-ups, I will keep the SharePoint Groups but remove the users and replace them with Active Directory (AD) Security Groups (SGs) containing those users.

I imagine that this code will then show those SG names, but not the users defined in each SG.

Is there a simple way to enhance this code, to show the users in those SGs?

Comment: Did you want to get users from Azure AD Security Groups? If so, check the Graph API. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/groups-operations

Comment: No, just terrestrial AD SGs.

Comment: Hmm, I have been presuming that the AD SGs are terrestrial, but since our SharePoint is cloudy (O365 tenant), maybe those would have been forced to Azure.  Is there a method that works for either platform?

Comment: If the AD SGs in On-Premise, as a workaround, we can get the ad groups using C# code and add the data into a custom list with permissions in SharePoint Online using CSOM C#, then get data from the custom list using REST API.